# Wrong customer account after login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account

I have a right login credentials, but after login it shows me a wrong customer account information like `Email`, `Id`, `Name` etc.

Can anybody solve it.

Comment: can you give me url of your site??

Comment: http://www.venumart.com

Comment: delete cache and session from var folder

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System > Configuration > Web` then:

1) Set `Use SID on Frontend` to `NO`

2) Set `Full page caching` to `NO`

3) Clear `Magento` and `Browser` cache.

Comment: Care to explain why this solution might help?

Comment: I invite you to read the Magento documentation !

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you, that was not my intention. I'm well familiar with the documentation. I just felt like it would be more convenient for the questioner to have a more elaborate answer.